# Authorizing issue with passport-jwt in a MERN project

Tags: node.js, authorization, passport.js, mern, passport-jwt

I am experiencing a problem with passport jwt.
Whenever i send a GET request adding authorization as `Bearer <generated-token>` in the header to the /profile route, i get a response which says "unauthorized". Here's a sample of what's happening:
https://ibb.co/qmYmfJs

Any idea what might be causing this issue?

The packages I am using are:

```
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "16.0.3",
    "express": "4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "7.0.4",
    "nodemon": "2.0.22",
    "passport": "0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "4.0.1"
```

I have this code on server/config/passport.js:

```
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = process.env.SECRET_KEY;

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    User.findOne({ _id: jwt_payload.sub })
        .then(user => {
            if (user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return done(err, false);
        });
}));
```

This on server/app.js

```
//login route
app.post("/login", async (req,res) =>{
    const user = await User.findOne({phone : req.body.phone});
    if(!user){
        res.status(400).send("User not found!");
    }
    if(!bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)){
        res.status(400).send("Incorrect password!");
    }

    const payload = {
        id: user._id,
        phone: user.phone
    }
    const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {expiresIn: "2d"});

    return  res.status(200).send({ success : true, message : "Log in successful", token : "Bearer "+token});
})

//profile route
app.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.status(200).send({
            message: "Tomar account", 
            token: "Bearer "+token,
            user: {
                id: req.user._id,
                phone: req.user.phone
            }
        }); 
    }
);
```

I am using thunderclient for testing the API endpoints. I have tried other ExtractJwt methods that does not use bearer tokens, such as `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt')` but that doesn't work also.